# wkhtmltopdf binary is not found plesk

Tags: php, cakephp, wkhtmltopdf, plesk

I am having trouble to execute the wkhtmltopdf executable on CentOS 7 with Plesk. I am running a website on CakePHP with the CakePdf plugin. All engines are working fine except wkhtmltopdf.

I installed wkhtmltopdf through the official rpm package (via root user). On the command line wkhtmltopdf works.
for example

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

will output

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)
```

when executing the code through php I will get an error

```
echo exec('wkthmltopdf -V 2>&1');
```

will output

```
sh: wkthmltopdf: command not found
```

In the php settings I have set open_basedir to none. And the error remains the same.

My best guess the issue is with the user? Maybe someone can give me some directions to try and fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to run `which wkhtmltopdf` to see where it is installed. Is this location in your PATH?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf which is also added as binary in the engine options.

Comment: Please update your question with the details of your engine configuration. It's pretty easy to get things at the wrong level.